# OpenCL conditional statement issue

Tags: if-statement, parallel-processing, opencl, global

I've attempted to parallelize a set of conditional statements, but the output does not match existing implementation after the first loop which contains the kernel executes (mapI is an int array of 135, and on the 60th index of the second loop it fails, totaling 195 calls to mapI). I've checked that all arrays are passing to and from the kernel correctly by comparing them to the existing implementation and am baffled as to why this computation does not return the correct result, as it does for the first loop of the code. All OpenCL overhead functions return CL_SUCCESS.

```
cl_mem Q1cl, Q3cl;
Q1cl = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(double)*um->Npts*um->Nel, Q1, &err);
Q3cl = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, sizeof(double)*um->Npts*um->Nel, Q3, &err);
nxcl = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, sizeof(double)*um->Nel*um->Nfaces*um->Nfq, nx, &err);
nycl = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, sizeof(double)*um->Nel*um->Nfaces*um->Nfq, ny, &err);
mapIcl = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(int)*(um->Nfq+um->Ninflow), mapI, &err);
mapFcl = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR, sizeof(int)*(um->Nfq+um->Nfar), mapF, &err);
fluxQ1cl = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, sizeof(double)*um->Nel*um->Nfaces*um->Nfq, *fluxQ1check, &err);

err = clSetKernelArg(kernel[7], 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&mapIcl);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel[7], 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&nxcl);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel[7], 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&nycl);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel[7], 3, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&mapFcl);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel[7], 4, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&Q1cl);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel[7], 5, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&Q3cl);
err = clSetKernelArg(kernel[7], 6, sizeof(cl_mem), (void*)&fluxQ1cl);

globalWorkSize[0] = Ninflow; //Old implementation, now NEL
globalWorkSize[1] = Nfar;    //Old implementation, now NFACES*NFQ

err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue[0], kernel[7], 2, NULL, globalWorkSize, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(queue[0], fluxQ1cl, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(double)*um->Nel*um->Nfaces*um->Nfq, *fluxQ1check, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

Kernel Code:

```
__kernel void umBC(__global int* mapI,
               __global double* nx,
               __global double* ny,
               __global int* mapF,
               __global double* Q1,
               __global double* Q3,
               __global double* fluxQ1)
{

int id, idF;
double e[9][2] = { {0, 0},  {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}, {0, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}};
double t_1 = 1. / 9.;
double uf = 0.;
double vf = 0.;

int globalx = get_global_id(0);
int globaly = get_global_id(1);
id = mapI[globalx];
fluxQ1[id] = ((e[1][0]*nx[id] + e[1][1]*ny[id]) < 0)*((Q1[id]-Q3[id] -2.*t_1*1.*(e[1][0]*uf+e[1][0]*vf)*3.) * (e[1][0]*nx[id] + e[1][1]*ny[id])) + 0.;

uf = 0.01;
vf = 0.;
idF = mapF[globaly];
fluxQ1[idF] = ((e[1][0]*nx[idF] + e[1][1]*ny[idF]) < 0)*((Q1[idF]-Q3[idF] -2.*t_1*1.*(e[1][0]*uf+e[1][0]*vf)*3.) * (e[1][0]*nx[idF] + e[1][1]*ny[idF])) + 0.;

}
```

Edit: Below is the working implementation, thank you again doqtor and Lee for your help. To implementthis I needed to change the way mapI and mapF worked to match the sizing of fluxQ.

```
__kernel void umBC(__global int* mapI,
               __global double* nx,
               __global double* ny,
               __global int* mapF,
               __global double* Q1,
               __global double* Q3,
               __global double* fluxQ1)
{

double e[9][2] = { {0, 0},  {1, 0}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}, {0, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}, {1, -1}};
double t_1 = 1. / 9.;
double uf = 0.;
double vf = 0.;

int globalx = get_global_id(0); //NEL
int globaly = get_global_id(1); //NFACES*NFQ

if(mapI[globalx*NFACES*NFQ+globaly] != NEL*NFACES*NFQ+1000){
    fluxQ1[globalx*NFACES*NFQ+globaly] = 0.0;
    if ((e[1][0]*nx[globalx*NFACES*NFQ+globaly] + e[1][1]*ny[globalx*NFACES*NFQ+globaly]) < 0){
        fluxQ1[globalx*NFACES*NFQ+globaly] = (Q1[globalx*NFACES*NFQ+globaly]-Q3[globalx*NFACES*NFQ+globaly] -2.*t_1*1.*(e[1][0]*uf+e[1][0]*vf)*3.) * (e[1][0]*nx[globalx*NFACES*NFQ+globaly] + e[1][1]*ny[globalx*NFACES*NFQ+globaly]);
    }
}
uf = 0.01;
vf = 0.;
if(mapF[globalx*NFACES*NFQ+globaly] != NEL*NFACES*NFQ+1000){
    fluxQ1[globalx*NFACES*NFQ+globaly] = 0.0;
    if ((e[1][0]*nx[globalx*NFACES*NFQ+globaly] + e[1][1]*ny[globalx*NFACES*NFQ+globaly]) < 0){
        fluxQ1[globalx*NFACES*NFQ+globaly] = (Q1[globalx*NFACES*NFQ+globaly]-Q3[globalx*NFACES*NFQ+globaly] -2.*t_1*1.*(e[1][0]*uf+e[1][0]*vf)*3.) * (e[1][0]*nx[globalx*NFACES*NFQ+globaly] + e[1][1]*ny[globalx*NFACES*NFQ+globaly]);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I had done this as a way to avoid branching when I was originally trying to figure out the issue. The error is present when there is a loop instead of global id's and with either the current setup or with if-statements. I will look into using select!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get wrong results because your kernel is not implemented correctly. @Lee already said that, I will try to further explain why.

Let's say for simplicity we consider executing kernel using 2x2 global range.

Now, the (globalx, globaly) for each work item will be:

```
(0, 0)
(0, 1)
(1, 0)
(1, 1)
```

so:

```
work item (0, 0) writes to fluxQ1[mapI[0]] and fluxQ1[mapF[0]]
work item (0, 1) writes to fluxQ1[mapI[0]] and fluxQ1[mapF[1]]
work item (1, 0) writes to fluxQ1[mapI[1]] and fluxQ1[mapF[0]]
work item (1, 1) writes to fluxQ1[mapI[1]] and fluxQ1[mapF[1]]
```

Assuming that mapI[0], mapI[1], mapF[0] and mapF[1] return unique ids then 2 work items write to the same location in parallel which obviously can't give you correct results. This will get worse if mapI and mapF can return same ids.
Some of the results you get correct by luck.

Changing number of global or local work items won't help, using `select` or not won't help either. You need to ensure work items don't write to the same location at the same time!

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple work-items in each dimension, yet you are writing to a location indexed by only one:

```
int globalx = get_global_id(0);
int globaly = get_global_id(1);
id = mapI[globalx];
fluxQ1[id] =
```

So multiple work-items here will share the same globalx. That means they will read the same id from mapI, and will write to the same location in fluxQ1.

Comment: Thank you for your response!

I had tried implementing this just as a static for loop before and it error'd in the exact same way. Is there any reason it goes through the computation correctly once before returning a bad number?

Do I just need to specify a local size of 1 in order to correct this behavior?

Comment: That wouldn't be very efficient, you wouldn't use the device effectively. You really need to change the algorithm to not update the same locations repeatedly - output to multiple locations and then reduce to a single location, for example. If the multiple directions of your original conditional collide on the same location, you probably need to put the conditional (or a select as mentioned earlier) back in to avoid it.

Comment: I've included the new kernel using select in an edit above, but the problem still exists. I've also set local size to 1x1 and removed globalization entirely in lieu of static for loops, but still the calculation fails to complete at the same index of the second run every time.

Comment: @Stumpae verify your arrays by using `printf` in the kernel code.

Comment: I've verified that every array going into the kernel reads from and matches the existing arrays outside of the kernel.